# Selenium interact with Google Drive

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently using Selenium to automate the downloading file from public Google Drive folder.

I use *browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "akerZd").click()* , but it just opens the browser with Drive page and does not do anything after. ("akerZd" is the name of class of small download button on the folder)

My code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mOGQW__azsRkJI-l4vFjcxwYO5DC8uEA')
element = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "akerZd")
element.click()
```

How can I do to solve this problems?
Have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
driver.get('https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mOGQW__azsRkJI-l4vFjcxwYO5DC8uEA')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"akerZd"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[name='ok']"))).click()
```

To simply download that file wait for the elements to be clickable and induce a click. I would also recommend not using that class name and using another identifier since it might be dynamic and change. If you know what files to get this would work too.

```
//div[.='NHV-BOOT-2021-800-STANDARD-ISO.zip']/preceding::div[@aria-label='Download' and @role='link'][1]
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

[image]

Comment: Somehow can't we avoid the index `[1]`?

Comment: //div[.='NHV-BOOT-2021-800-STANDARD-ISO.zip']/ancestor::div[@role='gridcell']//div[@aria-label='Download' and @role='link'] You could probably use this if you want instead.